# How to disable JAXB INFO message "cannot be unwrapped:

Tags: jaxb, cxf, wsdl2java

I'm using CXF WSDL2Java (using JAXB to generate Java classes).  I now have everything generating my classes fine, but I get INFO messages of the form;

```
Jun 15, 2016 4:39:16 PM org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder checkForWrapped
INFO: Operation <--my operation--> cannot be unwrapped, its wsdl:part/@element reference must match xs:complexType/xs:sequence.
```

I understand why it can't be unwrapped and don't have the option to "fix" the WSDL, it's already in use as is.

I'd like to pass something in so that I don't see these INFO messages during my build, as it just creates noise for something that's really OK.

How can I run WSDL2Java to avoid this message?

Comment: `-quiet` option is suitable for you? it seems there are no more options...

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure I want to shut off all INFO messages, At least it seems I haven't missed something, but it would definitely be nice to have a way to say "I know about this and don't want to be warned about it"

Comment: I have a similar issue with a RPC-Literal WSDL for which the wrapper/non-wrapper should not apply. Did anyone found a way to suppress these messages?